# How to implement image browsing with fading buttons inside the image

Tags: jquery, navigation, fade

I am developing an application for **browsing images**. I have already implemented the browsing mechanism by using standard text anchors outside the image.

Now I would like to implement the browsing mechanism "inside" the image. Let's make it clear. 
The user sees the image and upon **onMouseOver event**, depending on which side of the picture the pointer goes, it is shown an arrow respectively on the right or left side.
Upon **onClick event**, on the right or left side of the picture, the user should be able to browse to the previous/next image. It is not necessary to click on the arrow to browse.

Now I know that it is possible implement this function with Javascript, especially the jQuery framework has some interesting functions to do this. I am following this approach:

1. Create a div container for the image and place the `<img>` tag inside.
2. Define the position for the navigation arrows inside the container.
3. Upon **onMouseOver event** call a jquery function that places an arrow image in the position defined at step 2.
4. Use some **fading** function to implement the fade effect.
5. Upon click call the image browsing functions already implemented.

My doubts are mainly about:

Q1) Is my approach (above listed points) correct?

Q2) How can I adjust the position of the browsing arrows depending on the image size?

Q3) How can make jQuery "understand" whether the user is **onMouseOver** or **onClicked** to the left or right part of the image?

Although all the answers are appreciated, I am not asking plain code to copy paste and adjust in my application, but I would like to know whether my approach is correct and have a couple of useful jQuery (or any other JS framework) functions to implement this functionality.

Comment: ...and by the way tl;dr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: Your approach is going into the right direction.

Q2: With jQuery you can read out the width of an element or you can position the arrow element with `position:absolute; right:20px` ... but check Q3->

Q3: In your layover define two seperate `divs`, one on the right half the other on the left half over the image. So the structure could be:

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
   <img src="somthing.jpg"/>
   <div class="navigation-overlay">
      <div class="left-arrow></div>
      <div class="right-arrow"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. The markup you posted for **Q3** is not clear to me. I use the image-wrapper div as well but I put the z-index property. Where will you put the property in your example?

Comment: Ok now it is clear I have to play with CSS in order to position the elements. I read many articles about the z-index property but actually you do not need to use i in my case. Thanks